# Python function prints twice and I need to remove symbols

Tags: python, sqlite

For my function, I would like to access a database and get a command from searching functions of commands.

This is my code:

```
x="create vlan"
y="global"

def readswitch(x,y):

    conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
    with conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        run= cur.execute("SELECT command FROM switch WHERE   function =? or type = ?  ORDER BY key ASC",(x,y))
        read = cur.fetchall()
        return read;

import database
print (database.readswitch(x,y))
```

Now, I can printout my answer but there are a few mistake on the result as shown:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/Username/PycharmProjects/2015122/database.py
[('enable',), ('configure terminal',), ('vlan (number)',), ('name (vlan name)',)]
[('enable',), ('configure terminal',), ('vlan (number)',), ('name (vlan name)',)]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

There are 3 errors that I do not need it but I do not know how to fix

1. I printout my answer twice, but I do not get it why it print twice.
2. I expected that my answer should print in this sequence:

> ```
> enable
> conf t
> vlan (number)
> name (vlan name)
> ```

But it prints in a row.

3. I want to remove the symbol from:

> [('enable',), ('configure terminal',), ('vlan (number)',), ('name
>   (vlan name)',)]

to

```
enable
conf t
vlan (number)
name (vlan name)
```

Could anyone give me some advice for my function?
I hope that you can improve my function. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First let's address why you results are printing twice.

You have a module, `database.py`. It contains the lines

```
import database
print (database.readswitch(x,y))
```

You then execute the module from the command line with

```
$ python database.py
```

Before you reach the line with your `print`, you import the `database` module. This causes the module's code to execute a second time. That means the `print` is executing twice.

To fix this, don't import the module from within the module and just use

```
print (readswitch(x,y))
```

To be extra safe, you could place this inside a conditional.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print (readswitch(x,y))
```

Now we can address the format of your output.

The `fetchall` method results a `list`. When you print an entire list, it prints the contents of the list as a continuous string.

```
>>> print([1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c'])
[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

If you want to format the output, you need to take care of that yourself. The most straightforward way to do this is with a loop.

```
for command in readswitch(x, y):
    print(command[0])
```

You could also use `str.join`.

```
print('\n'.join(command[0] for command in readswitch(x, y))
```